# Can you get hashtag search results from twitter API to embed in a webpage?

Tags: twitter, fetch-api

Pretty much the title - I found service platforms that apparently let you do this but you have to pay. Is there no support in the twitter API itself to, say, get and display the 10 current top tweets for #Bitcoin on a web page?

Comment: There's no built-in web widget for this, no. You could use the Twitter search API on your backend to get 10 Tweets ("top tweets" is not something you can search for though), and then use the oEmbed API to get the Tweet embed code for each of those 10 IDs.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you!